# How can I display the extra column on the table I join with NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation: https://dbfiddle.uk/2Y8c0uCy with this query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                c.Id, c.ExternalId, c.Salary, c.EntityId, c.Hash
            FROM 
                ContractInnerJoin c
            WHERE c.ExternalId = 35
    ) as r
    WHERE
        not exists(select * from IntegrationMapping im where 
                                                            im.EntityInstanceId = r.Id AND 
                                                            im.ExternalId = r.ExternalId AND 
                                                            im.Hash = r.[Hash] AND
                                                            im.EntityId = r.EntityId)
```

I would like to display the OrderBodyId(56) column from the IntegrationMapping table, for the values that have been modified, that have a different Hash column.

In the example above, I selected the value that has a different Hash than what is found in the IntegrationMapping table, and for this I would like to find out the OrderBodyId, which in this case is 56.

In the first table, only the Salary column is changed, whose value was changed for the 3rd time, thus obtaining a different hash compared to IntegrationMapping. I would like to update the changed value, but I can't figure out how.

Or what would help me even more, to create an update procedure that would find the Hash different from the IntegrationMapping and update the Hash only for that different value.

Comment: I"m not certain I understand but probably you need to join on `im.EntityInstanceId = r.Id AND  im.ExternalId = r.ExternalId AND im.Hash <> r.[Hash] AND im.EntityId = r.EntityId`m to find the matching entity with a different hash. You need to join to extract any columns, you can't get any columns out of an `exists` predicate.

Comment: Perhaps you want to LEFT JOIN IntegrationMapping instead?

Comment: @jarlh yes, but doesn't work. I receive more 3 rows instead of one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Vladut you aren't JOINing anything right now. If you want results from both tables you need to use JOIN.  You *will* receive multiple rows if there are multiple matches. That means that either the JOIN conditions weren't enough or that there really are 3 matching rows and you need to decide which one to return. It may be enough to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with the columns you actually need instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want the value that is different than that two be updated, I don't needed the other two. Can you modify the query in that way?

Comment: Please show expected results. Putting it another way: how do you know which rows to join to which?

Comment: The comment is unclear and asks something different than what the *question* asks. The question asked how to add a 6th column, OrderBodyId, to the results. Assuming all matching rows have the same OrderBodyId then all you need is a JOIN and `SELECT DISTINCT Id, ExternalId, Salary, EntityId, Hash ,OrderBodyId`. If they have different values, you need to decide which one you want to keep

Comment: Id ExternalId Salary EntityId Hash
F50A1C9A-0F7B-4B33-9740-5DD3A429BEFF 35 25002 0E984208-62C7-4AB1-885B-E12FC8075B4A e98ce85068ca3edfe4f8d682670224f2 WITH another Column OrderBodyID 56, exactly the same table from my query with OrderBodyId in column with value 56.

Comment: By what logic are you joining those rows? There is nothing to correlate the 25002 with the 56? It sounds like the first table is missing the `OrderBodyId` column for joining

Comment: @Charlieface Is not possible by excluding the 2 that exist?

Comment: You're not explaining how you know which ones you want to match and which not. What do you do if `ContractInnerJoin` has four rows, and `IntegrationMapping` has five, one of which matches and the rest not? etc.

Comment: @Charlieface will never 5 and the other 4. Every time when I have a new row I will insterted into the IntegrationMapping. If the values is changed by the Hash I will updated,

Comment: Ok what happens if you have four in `ContractInnerJoin` and four in the other and none match, how do you knwo which to join with which?

Comment: @Charlieface only one value will be updated, the values from ContractInnerJoin are restricted, and only one will be updated, the line who has rights to be edited. The others rows will be closed.

Comment: Please add sample input and output data. and please be more descriptive than "doesn't work like that". Right now what you're asking for is ambiguous and even if you think certain data combinations won't happen, you need to code defensively for them, unless you have table constraints that ensure they don't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the "most interesting "structures i've came across, but it's always interesting to see something new. Why did you make the sync system this way?
Why are old values left hanging around from both sides? It makes zero sense and is riddled with danger.

But anyways, a potential solution is doing something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ContractInnerJoin r
cross apply (
   select top 1  * 
  from IntegrationMapping im 
  where  im.EntityInstanceId = r.Id 
  AND im.ExternalId = r.ExternalId 
  AND  im.Hash <> r.[Hash] -- Non-matching hash!
  AND im.EntityId = r.EntityId
  and not exists(
    select 1
  from contractinnerJoin jj
  where im.EntityInstanceId = jj.Id 
  AND im.ExternalId = jj.ExternalId 
  AND  im.[Hash] = jj.Hash
  AND im.EntityId = jj.EntityId
  )
  ) zz
WHERE r.ExternalId = 35
and not exists(
  select 1 
  from IntegrationMapping im 
  where im.EntityInstanceId = r.Id 
  AND  im.ExternalId = r.ExternalId 
  AND im.Hash = r.[Hash] 
  AND im.EntityId = r.EntityId
  )
```

What this does is identifying rows with non matching hash, and then getting the actual row with non matching hash (such row that doesn't have any other matching hashes already).

It's hard to know if this solves your problem because it all depends on how rest of the data looks, but maybe it's a start.

Comment: Thanks, yes is a good start for my structure!

Answer (score 1):

The following certainly works for the limited data you have given.  I don't know if it will work for a fuller set:

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT iSub.OrderBodyId, cSub.Hash
        FROM IntegrationMapping isub 
        INNER JOIN ContractInnerJoin csub ON
            csub.ExternalId = csub.ExternalId AND isub.EntityInstanceId = csub.Id
            AND csub.EntityId = isub.EntityId AND csub.Hash = isub.Hash) 
SELECT c.Id, c.ExternalId, c.Salary, c.EntityId, c.Hash AS CHash, im.Hash AS ImHash, im.OrderBodyId
FROM ContractInnerJoin c
INNER JOIN IntegrationMapping im
ON c.ExternalId = im.ExternalId AND im.EntityInstanceId = c.Id
AND c.EntityId = im.EntityId AND im.Hash <> c.Hash
WHERE im.OrderBodyId NOT IN (SELECT OrderBodyId FROM cte)
AND c.Hash NOT IN (SELECT Hash FROM cte)
```

This particularly supposes that the chances of two different sets of data can produce the same hash is negligible, but this is probably a reasonable assumption.

Comment: i will tested and will coming with an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two window fuctions counting the number of matches for the `Hash` column on each table. Then filter so that it only returns rows for which there are no matches on either side.

```sql
SELECT
  c.*
FROM (
    SELECT c.*,
      Im_Hash = im.Hash,
      im.LastSyncDate,
      im.OrderBodyId,
      countC = COUNT(CASE WHEN c.Hash = im.Hash THEN 1 END) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY im.EntityInstanceId, im.ExternalId, im.EntityId, c.Hash),
      countIM = COUNT(CASE WHEN c.Hash = im.Hash THEN 1 END) OVER 
        (PARTITION BY im.EntityInstanceId, im.ExternalId, im.EntityId, im.Hash)
    FROM ContractInnerJoin c
    LEFT JOIN IntegrationMapping im
      ON im.EntityInstanceId = c.Id
     AND im.ExternalId = c.ExternalId
     AND im.EntityId = c.EntityId
    WHERE c.ExternalId = 35
) c
WHERE c.countC = 0
  AND c.CountIM = 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/1B_bZXPV)